# Set variable for use in different make target

Tags: makefile

I have a make target that calls another, I want to set the variables in the make target that calls the target it depends on and pass the variables down.

```
FILENAME ?=
SERVICE ?=

generate-transaction-command: generate-service
   FILENAME := swagger.json
   SERVICE := transaction
    
    
generate-service:
   @curl -s http://localhost:8181/swagger/proto/$(FILENAME) --output ./$(FILENAME)
   @./gen -input ./$(FILENAME) -output ./cli/cmd/$(SERVICE).go
```

I want to be able to run `make generate-transaction-command` and then my `generate-service` command uses the variables set in the `generate-transaction-command`, at the moment it gives me this error.

```
FILENAME: No such file or directory
```

So I assume it isn't setting the variables correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Target-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)
Example:

```
FILENAME ?=
SERVICE ?=

generate-transaction-command: generate-service
    @echo $@ recipe

# set variables for a target:
generate-transaction-command: FILENAME := swagger.json
generate-transaction-command: SERVICE := transaction

# added echo
generate-service:
    @echo curl -s http://localhost:8181/swagger/proto/$(FILENAME) --output ./$(FILENAME)
    @echo ./gen -input ./$(FILENAME) -output ./cli/cmd/$(SERVICE).go
```

output:

curl -s http://localhost:8181/swagger/proto/swagger.json --output ./swagger.json
./gen -input ./swagger.json -output ./cli/cmd/transaction.go
generate-transaction-command recipe